# In ubntu after installing generator-hyperledger-composer . the generator-hyperledger-composer: command not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

for installing i use nvm the other things like yomen and composer-cli are working properly
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI2wR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator-hyperledger-composer does not register a command itself.  It is a module for Yeoman, so it is used for example `yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork`.

You can see how to use the generator in the [Composer Developer Turorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial), and in the [Readme file in Github](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/tree/master/packages/generator-hyperledger-composer).

( If you need to check the version you can use `npm ls -g -depth=0` )